# Update select for specific cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big database with hundreds of tables. So I made a select that gives me the data I need. I now want to update a value from one column for all the rows depending on the circumstances.

I know it's something to do with UPDATE and SET for the cases and stuff but I don't grasp the exact syntax. I have a problem accessing the specific column.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2  on Table1.ID=Table2.ID 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 on Table2.Item = Table3.Item 
  WHERE Table3.Item in (SELECT ChildItem
FROM Table4
WHERE Item=1000)
```

So this is the select Statment for all the columns. Now in one of the tables there is a column named columnA.

```
When ColumnB=0 and ColumnC<> 0 then ColumnA should be 1
When ColumnB<>0 and ColumnC=0 then ColumnA Should be 0

Else Column A Should not be changed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent unnecessary updates put the condition *Else Column A Should not be changed* in the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ColumnA = CASE 
  WHEN ColumnB = 0 and ColumnC <> 0 THEN 1 
  WHEN ColumnB <> 0 and ColumnC = 0 THEN 0 
END
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table2.Item = Table3.Item 
WHERE Table3.Item IN (
  SELECT TABLE4.ChildItem
  FROM Table4
  WHERE TABLE4.Item = 1000
)
AND ((ColumnB = 0 and ColumnC <> 0) OR (ColumnB <> 0 and ColumnC = 0))
```

You must qualify the columns ColumnA, ColumnB and ColumnC with the table's name.

Comment: That worked very good. Putting the cases in the Where clause gave also the benefit that it spits only the amount of records out that are affected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET COLUMNA = (CASE WHEN ColumnB=0 and ColumC <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2  
     ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID LEFT JOIN
     Table3 
     ON Table2.Item = Table3.Item 
WHERE Table3.Item IN (SELECT TABLE4.ChildItem
                      FROM Table4)
                      WHERE TABLE4.Item = 1000
                     );
```

I am guessing that `TABLE1` is the table to be updated.

Your description of the value for `COLUMNA` does not cover all possibilities.  You also `LEFT JOIN` to `TABLE3`, but the `WHERE` clause turns this into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works well. 

Can you elaborated why a left join with a where clause is an inner join or maybe just tell me how the inner join would look like?